# Need to adjust the line height in a visualforce page paragraph

Tags: visualforce

I want to do two things with this paragraph that is in the middle of our Visualforce Page.

1. Make the line height a little bigger so it doesn't look so scrunched up and I want to make the margins a little bit narrower so it wraps around at the right spot.

**Here is my code.**

```
<apex:outputText style="align left"  ><p>

<apex:outputLink value="https://www.google.com/" style="color:Blue;"> link </apex:outputLink> to the recent M1 Webinar explaining People Based Marketing.</p></apex:outputText>
```

Here is pic if that might help:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i dont see any relevant code of you attempting to do so, can you provide what and how yuo are trying this?

Answer (score 2):

This is basic CSS, and the line-height attribute can easily be used to achieve what you want.

```
<apex:outputText style="attribute: value;" > </apex:outputText>
```

Please consider researching or attempting to do so yourself prior to posting these kinds of questions in the future. for example, if you did use the attribute, and it doesnt work for whatever reason, it would be good to know. We re mostly here to help you out with problems you encounter.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: thanks everyone.  I had researched for a couple of hours before posting this.  This what I ended up using.    <p style="line-height:170%;font-size:110%;" >